# Replace "o" with "0" in large wordlist and save the original word?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a large text file with words. Every word is on a single line (typical wordlist).

I want to replace all characters "o" with the number "0" in every word, and the new formed word to be pasted on the next line after the original word.

For example, if we have this two in the list:

```
dog
someone
```

After the manipulation, our file should looks like this:

```
dog
d0g
someone
s0me0ne
```

How this can be done with GNU tools like `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: I hope you don't intend to create passwords that way ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 'p' -e 's/o/0/g' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `-i`: activates in-place editing of the file
- `-e 'p'`: just pastes the line
- `-e 's/o/0/g'`: replaces o with 0 and pastes the altered line

And if you want an `awk` solution:

```
awk '1;gsub("o", "0")' file >new_file
```

Comment: You may also want to change the awk statement to `awk '1;gsub("o", "0")' file` so that it does not print two of lines where the `o` is not changed

Answer (score 7):

chaos' answer is good if every line matches. But if some lines don't contain a `o`, they'll be duplicated.
For example:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar' | sed -e 'p' -e 's/o/0/g'
foo
f00
bar
bar
```

Here are some other solutions which don't duplicate lines:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar' | sed -e '/o/ p; s//0/g' 
foo
f00
bar
```

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar' | perl -pe '/o/ && print; s/o/0/g'
foo
f00
bar
```

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar' | awk '{ print } /o/ { gsub(/o/, "0"); print }' 
foo
f00
bar
```

Comment: You don't need `o` in `s/o/0/g`, just `sed -e '/o/ p; s//0/g'`.

Comment: it may not be needed, but I prefer the clarity

Answer (score 3):

Another `sed` solution:

```
sed -ne 'p;s/o/0/pg' file

$ printf '%s\n%s\n' 'foo' 'bar' | sed -ne 'p;s/o/0/pg'
foo
f00
bar
```

**Explanation**

- `-n` option causes `sed` suppress the default output.
- `p` command write the pattern space to standard output.
- `s/o/O/pg` replaces all occurences (`g` flag) of `o` with `0`, only write pattern space to standard output if a replacement was made (`p` flag).

Comment: Why not just do `sed 'p;s/o/0/g'` ?

Comment: @Jidder: It will duplicate line without match, like `bar` in example.